# Are custom Joomla 1.6 templates compatible with Joomla 2.5.?

Tags: joomla

I have a simple question for you guy's. I am learning how to create custom Joomla template from scratch at Lynda.com but its tutorials are for Joomla 1.6. and I would like to know are Joomla 1.6. custom templates compatible with Joomla 2.5.? Thank You!!

Comment: Well guess they are!! I have managed to install my custom template in Joomla 2.5 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes they most likely are, as well as the joomla 1.6 extensions are compatible with joomla 2.5.

[some joomla extensions](http://offlajn.com)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Joomla 1.6 templates can be used with Joomla 2.5. Provided you change the manifest file accordingly.